# Can't set source in DropdownField

Tags: php, silverstripe

I want to choose in dropdown field name of Sender

```
DropdownField::create('Sender','Sender')->setSource(Member::get()->map('ID','FirstName'))->setEmptyString('Select one'),
```

In CMS I see FirstName. But when I render in template

```
<% loop LettersSearchResults %>
   ......
      <td >$Sender</td>
```

it shows ID, not Firstname. What's the matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Member::get()->map('ID','FirstName')` is setting ID as key and FirstName as title so ID will be saved in the database - title is only used to populate the dropdown.

If you have a has_one relation on teh Dataobject you're saving in to you can save the SenderID and can do `Sender.FirstName` in the template instead.

Comment: Thank you Lorentz for solution!